# Getting error - Error: write EPIPE in the .env.local file

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error pointing at `.env.local`

> Error: write EPIPE

Any thoughts?

Comment: You haven't shown any code. There's no way to understand where this error is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the quotes from the environment variable values.

Change

```
VARIABLE="SomeString"
```

to

```
VARIABLE=SomeString
```